# Working with UTF-8 vs UTF-16 vs UTF-32 internally within C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I only have experience with processing ASCII (single byte characters) and have read a number of posts on how people process Unicode differently which present their own set of issues.

At this point of my very limited exposure to Unicode, I’ve read that internal processing with **UTF-16 presents portability and other issues**.

I feel that **UTF-32 makes more sense than UTF-16** since all Unicode characters fit within 4 bytes but would consume more resources, especially if you are mainly dealing with ISO-8859-1 characters.

**I humbly feel that UTF-8 could be an ideal format to work with internally** (especially for case where you deal mainly with English and Latin based characters) since the ASCII range of characters would be handled byte by byte very efficiently.  Characters from the Latin alphabet would consume two bytes and other characters would consume more bytes of course.

Another advantage that I see is that **UTF-8 strings could be stored within regular C++ std::string or C string arrays** which seems so natural.

The disadvantage for using UTF-8 for me at least is that I have not found any libraries to support UTF-8 internally.  For example, I have not found any libraries for UTF-8 case conversion and substring operations.

Another disadvantage for me is that I have not found functions to parse bytes within a UTF-8 string for character processing.

Would it be feasible to work with UTF-8 internally and are there any **support libraries available** for this purpose?  I do hope so but if not, I think that my best option would be to forget using UTF-8 internally and use **Boost::Locale** since I’ve read that **ICU** is a mature library used by many to handle Unicode.

I would really like to hear your opinions on this matter.

Comment: Conversion to upper/lower case and substrings are rather easy (and less needed than usually thought). You normally parse the input and then just work with strings as atomic values. Exceptions are rare. If you are in the realm of one of those exceptions, you probably want ICU. If you don't need the full power of ICU, you may want to look at some lightweight utf-8 libraries such as [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I would store as immutable utf-8, and write utf-32 iterators for reading, and insert as utf-32.  Use substring 'views' (maybe with reference counts to source) for substring ops.  This gives simple character access, and compact storage.

Comment: *"UTF-8 strings could be stored within regular C++ std::string or C string arrays"* So what about about `std::u16string` and `char16_t const*`?

Comment: I don't quite see a precise question in here. There's `Would it be feasible" (where the answer probably is just a "yes") and "are there any support libraries" which is a resource request (and they're often frowned upon / [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: @dyp, It's difficult to be precise with this because I'm looking for opinions and suggestions about a topic I found very little on.  Support libraries can mean all the difference in determining whether a programming task is feasible or practicable.

Comment: "So what about about std::u16string and char16_t const*".  I haven't work with them but it does not seem natural to me since you are trying to fit a all characters into 16 bit which I don't think is possible.  But what is your opinion on working with UTF-8 internally?

Comment: The encoding you should use internally can depend on the libraries you will use. For instance, I use DirectWrite, which only accepts UTF16 strings, so I store every string in memory in UTF16, using a homegrown utf16string type (basic_string templated on unsigned short). For converting, I used this simple portable library with success: http://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/. Also, you might want to clarify your question, because it is a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: @Mark, I appreciate your comment.  My opinion is that what you use internally should not depend on the libraries you use but rather what you feel most comfortable processing text with.  A conversion can then be made to the format used by your library.

Comment: @n.m.: *"Conversion to upper/lower case and substrings are rather easy"*. How so? You surely know the infamous German "ß", which becomes "SS" in uppercase letters. Correct German conversion from upper to lower case therefore requires almost intelligent natural language parsing, because "BUSSE" may become "Busse" or "Buße" depending on which word is actually meant (and on whether you are in Switzerland or in Germany or Austria).

Comment: I would have been equally comfortable with using UTF-16 or UTF-8, however, by using UTF-16 internally I saved the overhead of converting every string to another encoding at runtime just to render it with DirectWrite.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I mean they are no harder than with utf32 or any other single-code-unit encoding.

Comment: @n.m. To me it seems quite a bit more difficult since UTF-8 is not fixed width and wouldn't you have to check the high order bits for 1s followed by a zero to determine how many bytes the character consumes?  If you have a code snippet showing how to set the case for a non-ASCII character or even how to properly traverse a UTF-8 string, that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: To traverse: if your locale's native encoding is UTF-8, you can just use mblen(); otherwise, look at UTF8-CPP. To convert case: convert one char to wchar_t, change case, convert back (should occupy the same number of bytes). But you probably shouldn't need it too often.

Comment: UTF8everywhere.org is evangelical about the solution you hit on, but they have a real point. There's a lot of support for UTF-8 in the language, it takes up less memory, and there are no byte-order issues. Furthermore, now that there are combining characters and variants, you don't really even get fixed width with UCS-32 anyway.

Comment: @Davislor, I had looked at features built into the language but was too lacking.  I will post some additional benefits that just came to mind in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into my very old answer and I'll tell you what I ended up doing.  I decided to stick with **UTF-8** and **store my data in std::string or single byte char arrays**.  There was never a need for me to use multi-byte characters!

The first library that I used was UTF8-CPP which is very easy to bring into your app and use.  But you soon find that you need more and more capability.

I really wanted to avoid using ICU because it is such a large library, but once you build it and get it installed, you begin to wish that you had done it in the first place because it has everything you need and much, much more.

What are my benefits you may wonder:

- I write truly portable code that builds under VC++ for Windows or GCC for Linux.
- ICU has everything, and I mean everything you need concerning unicode.
- I am able to stick with my beloved std::string and char arrays.
- I use many open source libraries in my apps with zero issues.  For example, I use RapidJson for my JSON to create in-memory JSON objects containing UTF-8 data.  I'm able to pass them to a web server or write them to disk, etc.  Really simple.
- I store my data into Firebird SQL but you need to specify your varchar and char field types as UTF8.  This means that your strings will be stored as mutli-byte in the database.  But this is totally transparent to you, the developer.  I am certain that this applies to other SQL databases as well.

Drawbacks:

- Large library, very scary and confusing at first.
- The C++ was not written by C++ experts (like the Boost developers).  But the code is totally stable and fast.  You may not like the syntax used though.  What I've done is to "wrap" common procedures with my code.  This pretty much means that I include my own UTF-8 library which wraps the ICU uglies.  Don't let this bother you because ICU is totally stable and fast.
- I personally dynamically link ICU into my applications.  This means that I first built ICU dynamically for my Win and Linux 64 bit environments.  In the case of Windows, I store the dlls in a folder somewhere and add that to my Windows path so that any app that requires ICU can find the dlls.

When I looked at built-in language features, I found several lacking such as lower/upper case conversion, word boundaries, counting characters, accent sensitivity, string manipulation such as substrings, etc.  Local support is also totally amazing.

I guess that summarizes entire exercise in UTF-8.